# Is it a spam or not an answer?

Tags: discussion

Shall I flag this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523332/bluetooth-device-not-detected/626413#626413) as being a *spam* or *Not an answer* ?

Comment: It should be flagged as Not an Answer.

Comment: @Mitch Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upheld Spam flags get people blocked at network level. They're a powerful tool to stop spammers filling up sites by simply cutting off their access.

They are for *spam* though. While there are [many definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming), I think "unsolicited advertisement" probably best recognises the sorts of posts we would want to block.

Solicited, relevant self-promotion is different, and often wouldn't warrant a spam flag. This is outlined in the final block of [our behaviour help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/behavior).

Things that just shouldn't *be there* (should be a comment, offensive, duplicate posting, etc, etc) have their own flags or can fall into the "For moderator attention" flag. Technically bad posts probably need editing, or a downvote and comment.

<sub>There are, of course, exceptions to everything I've said. Except that. And that.</sub>